# An error has occurred: Error connecting to the server: FATAL: Could not open file "base/12135/11946": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql

Can any one help me from this issue i am not able to rectify in Postgresql 9.4 installed in Windows 7 Professional.

An error has occurred: Error connecting to the server: FATAL: Could not open file "base/12135/11946": No such file or directory  in Postgresql 9.4 OS:- Windows 7 32 bit

But here services are starting not login into pgadmin III .Above error is showing

Comment: looks like one of your database files is missing ? have you deleted this after creating / initialising a new db ? Restore or re-install maybe your best options. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/storage-file-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

Judging from a similar problem discussed previously - [(PostgreSQL) ERROR: could not open relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875400/postgresql-error-could-not-open-relation) - the only solution might be restoring from a (hopefully existing) backup.

As it wasn't specified in detail: Have you tried connecting to the system using the super user account (usually postgres) and the corresponding database?